# Android - Map screen closing automatically

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

I have a Firebase Chat application that is working fine. However I have some issue with map that is always just closing down.

There is a feature in the app that will allow users to post their (Location).

Whenever I open the map screen - then it utomatically closes.

The application itself is NOT crashing, Im only having issue with the map screen.

This is my build.gradle(Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.startup.chat"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    compile 'life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.1.3-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
    compile 'com.afollestad:easyvideoplayer:0.3.0'
    compile 'ru.alexbykov:nopermission:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is Manifests file

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/map_key" />
```

This is Logcat output

```
12-08 16:19:14.152 12600-12629/com.senseidev.ipyre V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
12-08 16:19:18.332 12600-12600/com.senseidev.ipyre D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
12-08 16:19:18.335 12600-12629/com.senseidev.ipyre V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 9189
12-08 16:19:18.336 12600-12629/com.senseidev.ipyre V/FA: Using measurement service
12-08 16:19:18.336 12600-12629/com.senseidev.ipyre V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-08 16:19:18.338 12600-12629/com.senseidev.ipyre V/FA: Activity paused, time: 4131815
12-08 16:19:18.342 12600-12629/com.startup.chat D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=9189, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ChatActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3660273493638676481}]
12-08 16:19:18.355 12600-12629/com.startup.chat V/FA: Using measurement service
12-08 16:19:18.355 12600-12629/com.startup.chat V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-08 16:19:18.363 12600-12629/com.startup.chat D/FA: Connected to remote service
12-08 16:19:18.363 12600-12629/com.startup.chat V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
12-08 16:19:18.412 12600-12629/com.startup.chat V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 4131891
12-08 16:19:18.412 12600-12600/com.startup.chat D/AppTracker: App Event: start
12-08 16:19:18.416 12600-12600/com.startup.chat D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
12-08 16:19:18.420 12600-12629/com.startup.chat V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 9
12-08 16:19:18.421 12600-12629/com.startup.chat V/FA: Activity paused, time: 4131900
12-08 16:19:18.668 12600-12632/com.startup.chat D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x723e582800 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0x723ce4ada0
12-08 16:19:18.756 12600-12629/com.startup.chat V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 4132235
12-08 16:19:18.760 12600-12600/com.startup.chat D/AppTracker: App Event: start
12-08 16:19:23.760 12600-12629/com.startup.chat V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
12-08 16:19:30.859 12600-12611/com.startup.chat I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=1008KB, data=658KB
12-08 16:19:30.863 12600-12611/com.startup.chat I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=974KB, data=558KB
```

Im not understanding what the issue is - The map screen opens up but then automatically closes. I hope I can get a fix on this as this is very annoying bug.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you have **delete nodes in firebase database**. **reset your database** everything will works fine